# Find whitespace and add line break on a text file C#

Tags: c#

Hi id like to transform this file from this

```
KES 32265   5000001 1   10  COPY    05

KES 32265   5000001 1   10  PRINT   05

KES 32265   5000001 1   30  PRINT   05

KES 32265   5000001 10  100 PRINT   05
```

To this:

```
KES
100317
6114488
1
-
10.00
KPC1
-
-
5
-

KES
100317
6114488
1
-
30.00
KPC3
-
-
05
-
```

in a text file using C# Here's my Code.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\DestinationFolder");
        //if the director exists then proceed

        FileStream inFile = new FileStream(@"C:\x\KEN.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
        string record;
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            //the program reads the record and displays it on the screen
            record = reader.ReadLine();
            while (record != null)
            {
                //if (record.Contains(" "))
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine(record);
                //}
                //record = reader.ReadLine();
                ConvertWhitespaceToSpacesString(record);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //after the record is done being read, the progam closes
            reader.Close();
            inFile.Close();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string ConvertWhitespaceToSpacesString(string value)
    {
        value = value.Replace('\r', ' ');
        value = value.Replace('\n', ' ');
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you've tried, please post your code.

Comment: I can't see the connection between your input and your output.
If you want to change white space to a new line, you can simply use `Replace`: `str = str.Replace(" ", "\n");`

Comment: Input and output don't really match, do they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not quite clear what you are asking, in case you want the output to be in file aswell, you could try this FormatFile Function. Its reads all lines from file at once though, so be careful with bigger files. It loops through all lines then it splits that line on a whitespace character. Depending on what you want the output to look like you can alter the "if" statements. finally flush the StreamWriter down to the Filestream. All closing and disposing is done by the using statement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FormatFile(@"c:\test.txt");
}

public static void FormatFile(string pathToFile)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        foreach( string line in lines)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                continue;

            string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                string part = parts[i].Trim();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(part);
                }
                else //if( ... )
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("-");
                }
                //else if( ...)
                //{
                //    sw.WriteLine("KPC1");
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //
                //}
            }   
        }
        sw.Flush(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  I used string split method to remove the whitespaces. :

```
        try
        {
            //the program reads the record and displays it on the screen
            record = reader.ReadLine();
            while (record != null)
            {
                string[] array = record.Split(new char[] {' ', '\r', '\n', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
                foreach(string word in array)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                }

            }
        }
```